# Inaccurate preview of question

Tags: bug, edits, markdown-preview

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212005/how-to-browse-a-javascript-object)  has probably been made community wiki because many users tried to correctly format  the first block of code.

The problem is that it appears correct in preview:

[image]

But it is different after editing:

[image]

Comment: *infidel* preview? Did it trespass upon someones religion?

Comment: And the preview was entirely correct, it was the post rendering that was out of date. I've submitted an edit and it has been corrected.

Comment: Most editors changed other things in that post, so no, that post was not made CW because of that one thing.

Comment: "updated title, fixed grammatical mistakes, etc." And then a suggested edit came in with the exact same summary that was then improved on with an edit totally unrelated to the summary. What in the world.

Comment: The post does say _"12 revs, 8 users"_ but with @Martijn's edit there are only [9 revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14212005/revisions)...

Comment: @ben I know I tried more than once to do the same edit, which didn't work. And I assume others tried too. Hence the present bug report. What can make a "post rendering out of date" even after many reload ?